# Accessibility: Can a label have children besides the input?

Tags: html, accessibility, material-ui

Accessibility question: Can a `<label>...</label>` have children besides an `<input ... />`? We're using Material UI on a project and their `<Switch />` component is built like:

```
<label>
  <div>
    <span>
      <span>
        <input />
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</label>
```

which is triggering an accessibility error in HTML_Codesniffer.

Not sure if it's just not used to this structure and expects the `label` to be the direct parent of `input` or if it's an actual error.

Comment: Nope: https://validator.w3.org/ - very clear error https://i.imgur.com/XyDTf9A.png

Comment: Read that before I posted. Read it again after you posted. The "permitted content" section says nothing about having issues with non-labelable content. "Phrasing content, but no descendant label elements. No labelable elements other than the labeled control are allowed."

Comment: @AlonEitan And that doc clearly says that phrasing content is accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can a label have children besides the input?

Yes, and fortunately (or it will be impossible to format the text label). The following is permitted for instance

```
<label>
  <span>My input label</span>
  <input type="text" />
</label>
```

[According to the documentation](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#elementdef-label) it can contain any phrasing content:

> Phrasing content, but with no descendant labelable elements unless it is the element’s labeled control, and no descendant label elements

In your example, you can't have a `div` as it's a flow content not a phrasing content although browser and assistive technologies have support for it.

Note that the *accessibility error* in HTML_Codesniffer might not be linked to that problem, but to the fact that this tool does not link correctly the `label` with the `input`.

Answer (score 0):

inline elements aren't actually designed for containing elements maybe you should use "div" instead of "span"

Comment: Yeah, I've submitted an issue to Material UI. Thanks.